# Instantanous and uniform velocity and acceleration

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity, differentiation, calculus

1. If the mathemical expression of instantanous velocity is $d/t$, what is the mathematical expression of uniform velocity.
2. If the mathematical expression of instantanous acceleration is $v/t$, what is the mathematical expression of uniform acceleration.

Please make a note that I am not looking for definition of any of it.

If the post has one too many questions please either ignore the second question or edit/delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Instantaneous speed is defined as $d/t$ where the speed is recorded such that $t$ *is infinitesimally small* to correspond to the speed of that object at that *very* time instant while average speed is defined with t being the *total time taken (sufficiently big) to traverse the total distance over that time interval.*

A similar explanation can be extended to **no. 2)**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Uniform speed would just be represented by a scalar, like v = 2 $ms^{-1}$ similarly uniform acceleration would be just a vector with components in each direction or a single direction, $\vec{a} = 2$ $ms^{-2}$.